# Как правильно наименовать файлы php?

Tags: php

Есть куча файлов php, в каждом из которых небольшие функции для выполнения задач (нахождение суммы, разницы и т.д), подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно наименовать эти файлы в соответствии со всеми стандартами? Когда речь идет об ООП, то там понятно, название идет от имени класса, но когда дело касается обычной функции пока не знаю как правильно.

Comment: Именуй так же, как и классы  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: +1 к предыдущему оратору. Тут не ясно с какой целью это было сделано, но именуйте тогда по названию функции, как и классы

Comment: @Pashok спасибо